# Phonegap Build Iphone Orientation lock to portrait only

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

How to lock orientation in phonegap build to only portrait?

And if need to use plugin then please mention config.xml line for adding plugin so I can get more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line in your config.xml file

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

See more here:
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences

The community support page is also a good place to find information:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi

Comment: This is not working for android

Comment: @Haider It does, are you using Phonegap Build to build the app? It doesn't work if you're using the CLI.

Comment: I am using PhoneGap Desktop to create projects and using PhoneGap Developer App from play store to run the application.

Comment: @Haider My answer won't work then, it only works when using [phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com) .